# Video is not rendered on mobile - aframe

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli, aframe, 360-virtual-reality

I am building a project with `aframe` and `angular-cli` where I display a 360° video for virtual-reality. It works perfectly fine on desktop, but  on mobile it doesn't render it and the `console` prints the following warnings which don't appear on desktop:

[image]

Even though I am using `angular2`, I am including the script in the `<head>` tag since it doesn't work if importing the library in the component. This is instead the code of the `html` file:

```
<a-scene auto-enter-vr>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="video" src="../../assets/videos/Ski+Jump-7k_encoded.mp4" autoplay loop playsinline webkit-playsinline muted></video>
  </a-assets>
  <a-videosphere src="#video" rotation="0 360 0"></a-videosphere>
</a-scene>
```

I have looked into different sources, but I am not able to understand why the video is not rendering. Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: What type of mobile device? See: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1846

Comment: I have tested it on different devices: iPhone 6, Galaxy s6 and Galaxy s5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well chrome blocks the playback of all kind of media automatically to reduce data consumption. Video would only be loaded on a user gesture for example a click .

So for this to work on aframe we have to load up the video on click of an element . This is best done on click of the VR Goggles Icon . Here is some sample code to help you out .

```
var VRButton = document.querySelector('.a-enter-vr-button');
VRButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.play();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I have managed to simulate a click `OnInit()` and now it correctly works

Comment: glad to be of help